# Flutter: Exception: Profile mode is not supported for sdk gphone x86 arm

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in `Flutter`. I face a problem about `Profile mode is not supported for sdk gphone x86 arm`.

This is my `Debug Console`:

```
Exception: Profile mode is not supported for sdk gphone x86 arm.
Exited (1)
```

[image: Debug Console picture]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the "Run" button at the top of Visual Studio Code. Then, click the "Start debug".

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Run" button. Then, click the "Start debug"

Comment: I didn't see a 'Run' button on the OP's image.

Comment: The "Run" button is at the top of Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Click the **[Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKKR4.png)** button at the top of Visual Studio Code. Then, click the **[Start Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ASi1.png)** button.